# Expected Contextual keyword 'on'

Tags: linq

I need to do a left outer join on one table with multiple where conditions.I get the error msg on my select saying "Expected Contextual keyword 'on' ".In My below code my first where is for that particular table **CourseDbset** on which I need to do a left outer join.My second where is applied on my resultant data to filter the data based on status value.I apologize if i'm not being clear.

```
var StudentsInfo  =(from user in context.aspnet_Users
                                    join lc in context.class on                      
                                         user.userId equals lc.userId
                                    join course in context.CourseDbSet
                                    .Where(o => o.courseId == sessionId && o.enrollId = sessionid
                                    && o.deptID == sessionoddeptid).DefaultIfEmpty()

                                    select new
                                   {
                                     userid = user.UserId,
                                     username = user.UserName,
                                     status   = course.status

                                   }).Where(o => o.status == 0 || o.status == 3 || o.status == 4 || o.status is DBNull).ToList();
```

Comment: You have a 2nd join with no criteria.

Comment: You have the right idea, but left joins require different syntax. See [this post from the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx) and [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092562/left-join-in-linq) to get a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your first join (which is correct):

```
join lc in context.class 
  on user.userId equals lc.userId
```

And thats your second join (which is wrong):

```
join course in context.CourseDbSet
                      .Where( o => o.courseId == sessionId && 
                                   o.enrollId = sessionid && 
                                   o.deptID == sessionoddeptid ).DefaultIfEmpty()

// missing on statement
[on user.SOMETHING equals course.SOMETHING]
```

// EDIT

Ups.. i missed the `.DefaultIfEmpty()` call. If you want to perform a left join then you need a something similiar to this:

```
join course in context.CourseDbSet
                      .Where( o => o.courseId == sessionId && 
                              o.enrollId = sessionid && 
                              o.deptID == sessionoddeptid )

// missing on statement && left join
   on user.SOMETHING equals course.SOMETHING
 into courseJoinData
 from courseJoinRecord in courseJoinData.DefaultIfEmpty( )
```

Comment: In my where clause at the very end I have issues with o.status == null.it gives me error "The cast to value type 'Int16' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type" . I need to get the rows even if the status field is null

Comment: @BVidhya you will get the rows even if `o` is null, but the check will fail when `o` is null and you will check further for `o.status == 1`. Try `.Where( o => o == null || o.status == 1 [...] )`. The null check needs to be first, because otherwise you can't check for status.